# Computing number of distinct values of variable by group - two codes providing different outputs (R)

Tags: r, distinct

Does anyone have any idea as to why the two chuncks of code below don't provide the same answer? In `mydata` I have individual-level information on several procedures performed by physician (identified as `id`) in hospital (identified as `hosp`) at period `ym`. I would like to compute the number of unique physicians working in a given hospital-period.

The two chuncks of code below groups the data by `hosp`-`ym`, computes the number of unique `id` and then compute the average number of these unique physicians by hospital-period. The only difference is that, in the first code, I included the function `distinct(hosp,ym,id)` before computing the distinct number of `id` by `hosp`-`ym`. I would expect this line to be redundant, but it seems like it changes the output.

```
> mydata %>%
+   filter(!is.na(id)) %>%
+   group_by(hosp,ym) %>%
+   distinct(hosp,ym,id) %>% 
+   mutate(nids = n_distinct(id)) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   summarise(mean=mean(nids))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   mean
  <dbl>
1  10.6
```

Now commenting out the `distinct()` line.

```
> mydata %>%
+   filter(!is.na(id)) %>%
+   group_by(hosp,ym) %>%
+   # distinct(hosp,ym,id) %>% commented out
+   mutate(nids = n_distinct(id)) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   summarise(mean=mean(nids))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   mean
  <dbl>
1  9.26
```

Comment: In the first one, you you taking the `distinct` so that the number of rows will be less, while in second, it would be more and `mutate` create a column of the same number of rows as the data i.e. `mean(c(4, 4, 3))#
[1] 3.666667`
`mean(c(4, 3))#
[1] 3.5`

Comment: I am still a little confused. Which one would be the correct code to get the number of distinct `id` by `hosp`-`ym`? I would expect `n_distinct()` to only count the different observations of `id`. Thus, for this reason, I thought the different number of rows between the two codes would not matter.

Comment: The reason is how you many elements you are taking for the `mean`.  With `mutate`, you are creating an entire column of single value for each group (`n_distinct`), then you do the `mean`, but the number of rows matter here i.e. if a group have 3 row and other have 2, then n_distinct of first will be replicated 3 while the second one 2 times, changing the mean.  When you do `distinct` first, it is returning distinct rows, so the `mutate` step have less number of elements